# Mongodb PHP Driver MacOS Unsigned package error

Tags: macos, drivers, php, mongodb, macos-mojave

I installed MongoDB driver for PHP with the following command

```
sudo pecl install mongdodb
```

I had to disable "csrutil" at reboot to be able to run the above command.  After installing the package I added the extension=mongodb.so and I was able to see it both in phpinfo() and ran a small script (below) that verified the installation

```
<?php

 echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

 // Manager Class
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
echo "Successfully connected the manager";
?>
```

However, after I enable "csrutil" and reboot I am unable to load PHP driver for mongodb.  I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so,
>   0x0009): code signature in
>   (/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so) not
>   valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely
>   unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed. in Unknown on line 0

I am using PHP that came installed with macOS and my macOs version is Mojave Version 10.14.2.  How do I get PHP to see the unsigned package without having to disable "csrutil"?